# Can I combine two branches into a GitLab CI build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I know that GitLab CI will build each branch separately, but when I build the feature branch I want to compare some test results against the same tests on the master branch.
I could do that against the most recent build of master, or I'm happy to rebuild master on every feature branch commit if required.

Is that possible in GitLab CI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pipeline triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/) to build your `master` branch during a feature branch pipeline.

In your case I guess you want to wait for the `master` pipeline to complete. This is not the default Gitlab behavior.

Using a script called [pipeline-commander](https://github.com/cfriedt/pipeline-commander) you can wait for the trigger to complete.