# Initiating a job on another project from a gitlab job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been searching the internet for an answer but cannot find anything.

I have a gitlab yml file in one project and would like to start a job for a different project.

If this is possible I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, answered a similar question a few days ago, check it: [Can I combine two branches into a GitLab CI build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581801/can-i-combine-two-branches-into-a-gitlab-ci-build/47591815#47591815)

Bottomline, you can use [pipeline triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).